# Chat privilege details are incorrect

Tags: support, chat, description

At https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms we find:

> **How do I create a new chat room?**
>
> There is a link to chat in the footer of every page. The link also appears in the Stack Exchange site switcher on the upper right corner of every page. Click one of those links, and then click the "create a new room" button at the bottom of the Rooms page.

I believe that "There is a link to chat in the footer of every page" is wrong as I cannot find said link.

If the link is staring me in the face and I just need a good klunk to the noggin' then please feel obliged to do so.

Comment: It moved to the hamburger / stack exchange logo menu top right. (together with the `help` and `log out` links). So yes, that help text needs updating, which requires a developer or Community Manager.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, I did find it up there per sentence #2